# Error " undefined reference to `std::ios_base" while linking cpp header only library to fortran

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, gfortran

I am trying to link a header only library (which is in cpp) to a fortran code. I am using [this example](https://www.cae.tntech.edu/help/programming/mixed_languages) to test my library.

```
   $ cat cppfunction.C
   #include<cmath>
   #include<mylib/mylib.hpp>

   extern "C" 
   {
        void cppfunction_(float *a, float *b);
   }
   void cppfunction_(float *a, float *b)
   {
        *a=7.0;
        *b=9.0;
   }

  $ cat fprogram.f

   program fprogram

   real a,b
   a=1.0
   b=2.0

   print*,"Before fortran function is called"
   print*,'a=',a
   print*,'b=',b

   call cppfunction(a,b)
   print*,"After cpp function is called"
   print*,'a=',a
   print*,'b=',b

   stop
   end
```

For compiling I am using:

```
    $ gfortran -c fprogram.f
    $ g++ -c cppfunction.C
    $ gfortran -lc -o fprogram fprogram.o cppfunction.o
```

This runs fine if I remove my library header. But have this error when included:

```
    cppfunction.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
    cppfunction.C:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
    cppfunction.C:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anything I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content of `mylib.hpp`? You are probably including `iostream` or similar.

Comment: Why `#include<cmath>`?  Why `#include<mylib/mylib.hpp>`?

Comment: It seems the linker is linking with libc instead of libstdc++, in other words you need to link in C++ mode somehow.

Comment: What does `-lc` do?

Comment: @rveerd Yes. mylib contains function similar to std::cout to print variables.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0, links against libc.

Comment: @Evg: Wrong thing then isn't it.

Comment: It should be noted that the order of `-l` and object files in the command line **does** matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not linking the C++ standard library:

```
gfortran -lc -lstdc++ -o fprogram fprogram.o cppfunction.o
//           ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using this while compiling the .C file with g++.

Comment: @Evg Yes. I was using -lstdc++ while compiling with g++. The complete command in above answer helped.

Comment: `-lstdc++` should come **after** object files (at least, after C++ one), not before them. Otherwise, "undefined reference" is issued.

Comment: @AshishMagar Your `g++` invocation has `-c` (compile-only) so does not involve any libraries.